# Django Rest Framework ViewSets is returning selected records rather than all records in list view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django application. I have one part of my app that is not working as I was expecting. As of now I am using the django rest framework view sets. What I want is two basically have 2 different list views in the same viewset. 1 that returns all of the accounts in the accountviewset and another list view that returns all of the accounts associated with a user based on the user foreignkey in the account model.

The code below returns all the acccounts associated with a specific person, but I am not able to have a list view that returns all of the accounts in the database.

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Account.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AccountSerializer

        def get_object(self):
            return self.queryset.get(user__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

****UPDATE****

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all();
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('user', 'name', '_class')
    lookup_field = 'user__username'

    # def get_queryset(self):
    #     return self.queryset.filter(user__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

it works when there is one account associated with one user.
does not work with more than 2 accounts with error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/users/accounts/omarjandali/
get() returned more than one Account -- it returned 2!
```

other attempts doesnt return any accounts with a specific user or no user in the endpoint.

The biggest problem is that it returns an id of the user not user username.

[image]

current code:

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'gender', 'phone', 'ip_address', 'dob_month', 'dob_day',
                  'dob_year', 'address_street', 'address_city', 'address_state',
                  'address_postal', 'address_country', 'profile_pic', 'role')

class FriendSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ('requested', 'friended', 'status', 'blocked')

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(
        read_only = True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('user', '_id', 'name', 'balance', 'currency', 'bank_name',
                  'routing', '_class', 'type', 'active', 'main', 'synapse')
```

Views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'

class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'

class FriendViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FriendSerializer
    querset = Friend.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'

class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all();
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('user',)
```

urls:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'profiles', ProfileViewSet, basename='profile')
router.register(r'friends', FriendViewSet, basename='friend')
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet, basename='account')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: Please post the code in your urls.py

Comment: First, remove the `lookup_field` as it is used for detail endpoint lookups. So the view expects that whenever you do this `/api/users/accounts/omarjandali/` that only a single account should be found which is not the case in your setup. Secondly, if you're using filtering then the username should be added as a query parameter, not appended to the url. This is what it should look like `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/?usernamne=omarjandali`

Comment: Ok switched it as a query parameter, it does not show anything because when the object is returned, it shows up as `user:1` => `user:[user_id]`. I will add a picture of the returned objects in the post @Ken4scholars

Comment: It returns the data based on your serializer definition. User is related to account by id which is the foreign key so id is returned. If you want a different field, say username to show up, take a look at [serializers.SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

I would also just read the whole page on serializer relations to understand more how it works. The docs are pretty good and have answers to several common questions

Comment: It is displaying the entire user object for each of the accounts correctly. But the `username=omarjandali` is displaying all of the accounts. when i do `user=omarjandali` it says `"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."` for ` SlugRelatedField` and `UserSerializer.` It is not filtering based on the username parameter even though it is displaying it within the entire user object. @Ken4scholars the only way to get it to work is by using this `?user=4` rather than `?username=omarjandali`

Comment: i read the all the documentation and it was shwoing how to display the target field but the filtering part is still not working....

Comment: Can you show your current code? you don't have `user__username` in your `filterset_fields`. Also, rename it to `filter_fields`. I think that was a typo in the docs

Comment: I updated the post with all of my code that I have @Ken4scholars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a lot of issues with your code. If you need to return a list, then you should filter in the `get_object` method. it is meant to only return one single instance, so do that in the `get_queryset` method. Secondly, you have the `get_object()` inside your list method which is wrong. Thirdly, assigning the serializer class in the list method doesn't make sense. It is assigned before that method is even called.

Now back to your question, 'list' is a viewset action and you can't implement it twice. Instead you can add an [extra action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) on the list endpoint. 
To do this, just add a method in the action method in the viewset.

In your particular case I would do this: I will introduce an instance variable, `qs_type` which is used to control the type of result returned by the `get_queryset()` method.

Something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.qs_type = 'user_only'
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.qs_type == 'user_only':
        qs = Account.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    else:
        qs = Account.objects.all()
    return qs)


@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def all(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.qs_type = 'all'
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This assumes that by default, username filtered version is returned while the all accounts will be returned in the new action. You can make `qs_type` a boolean if you are sure you won't need more similar actions but I made it a string just in case. I don't know how your url is configured so I don't really know how the username is retrieved from the url kwargs, but this code should help you solve your problem

Comment: Ok. Thank you. question... So if I do it the way above, I am initiailzing the vewset and then creating two actions of the list view. It will check if there is a parameter that is passed into the end of the url. If it is, then filter, if it is now, show all. That is basially what is going right? What does the `@action` do to the list view?

Comment: Another question I have is... So I create the viewset and add the `serializer_class` and `queryset`, but then inside of the `def list` I will be creating the double action???

Comment: if I want to impliment this code, would I put it in the list def of the accounts view set or the general class of the account view set. Also are there any import statemtns that I need because I am getting an error with the `@action`

Comment: I linked the part of the docs about extra actions. You can read up the details there. You cannot create two list actions because those actions are just represented by methods. That would mean having 2 methods named `list` in the class which you should already know is not possible both in the Python context and DRF context. If you add a filter parameter (not url kwarg), it will be used in filtering but you don't have to do this in the `get_object`. It is used in the `filter_queryset` method. Please check the DjangoFilterBackend in django-filter to learn how to use filters in DRF views

Comment: I don't really understand your second question but you can't define the `get_object` inside the `list` action. You can change the serializer class but before processing. I don't really see you processing the request in the `list` method you defined. Your third question is also confusing. You have one single viewset serving both list and detail endpoints. So what do you mean by list of AccountViewSet? If you mean nesting it inside the `list` method then no. You shouldn't nest any action method inside other action methods

Comment: So what I want to do is be able to have two different returns based on whether there is a username in the endpoint url. If there is no username in the url endpoint, I want to return all of the accounts in the database. If there is a username in the url, I want to the accounts that have that username in the User Foriegnkey within the accounts model. How can I go about doing that....

Comment: @OmarJandali what exactly do you mean by a username in the endpoint? a url kwarg or filter? post your url as I requested as I'm yet to understand which one you mean.

Comment: so if i have something like `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/` I want to see a list of all the accounts in the database. if I have `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/omarjandali` I want to get all f the accounts associated with the `omarjandali` User. In the account model there is a foreignkey named user that stores the user model. I want to use the username as a filter with that User foreignkeys. does that help clarify.

Comment: If you want to use the username as filter then use it as a query param like this `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts?username=omarjandali`. Check the section of django filter on how to use it in DRF here https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#using-the-filterset-fields-shortcut

Comment: `/api/users/accounts/` and `/api/users/accounts/omarjandali` are different endpoints and can not both be implemented in the same viewset action especially since they should both return lists.You can use the approach I suggested in my answer by creating a different action for it.  And again honestly, I think you should read the documentation more because you seem to be mixing up detail view and list view without knowing properly which should be used when

Comment: would it be resonable to create two completely different viewset for each endpoint??

Comment: Well if you don't like the idea of a query param for filtering or implementing a separate action in the viewset as in my answer, then maybe you should make a spearate view for it. Although it doesn't make sense IMHO. It's logically part of the Accounts API and should belong to the viewset

Comment: So i am integrating the django-filter into the project. I was able to do what I wanted. get a list of all the accounts using `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts`. and when I add a username to the endpoint `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/omarjandali`, I get the accounts of each user except for when there is more than one account associated with a singel user. I tried two different ways of filtering. I will add the new code to the question below the existing code.

Comment: @OmarJandali This `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/omarjandali` is not filtering. It is just a separate endpoint. For filtering what you need is this `localhost:8080/api/users/accounts/?usernamne=omarjandali`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187455/discussion-between-omar-jandali-and-ken4scholars).